# Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute - React

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, typescript, cookies

I'm getting two errors when embedding a youtube video in my code.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The two images below refer to the second error:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The video was embedded as follows:

```
    <div className="video-responsive">
      <iframe
        width="200"
        height="115"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kS2mXX_sOEc"
        frameBorder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowFullScreen
        title="Embedded youtube"
      />
    </div>
```

Does this have to do with the cors? Can someone help me please?